# VRML loader in three.js rev 94 and above

Tags: three.js, vrml

I have a VRML model.file at: https://fe4d.com/tmap/assets/tube.wrl . I can load it with VRMLLooader in three.js rev 82. But when tried three.js rev 94 and rev 102, it failed. Has anybody had the same issue? What I need to do to load it in recent versions of three.js?

Comment: I can confirm that your `WRL` file loads with `R82` but not with the recent version (`R103`) of `VRMLLoader`. Could be a regression. I think it's best when you file an issue at github.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was caused by a regression in `THREE.VRMLLoader`. It was fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/16227). Please use current `dev` version of `three.js` or wait for the next release `R104`.